# Methods to track player movements including distance

Tags: football

What is the best way to measure althetic performance in a game of football. I am thinking some sort of consumer level GPS product, a bit like [this product](http://gpsports.com/) but that seems not available on a personal level.

Does what I am looking for exist?

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about measuring your own performance, there are certain shoes which have a gps tracker installed. For example the [Adidas F50 adizero](http://www.gizmag.com/adidas-adizero-f50-football-boot/20030/)

<s>If you don't want to buy an extra shoe for this there are also various sports watches with gps-trackers installed.</s> As mentioned in comments, wearing accessories is not allowed in official games.

Comment: In an official game you would not be allowed to wear a watch though.

Comment: Yeah true. Didn't think about that, thx.